# Installing web nodejs add-in (migrating from localhost to web url)

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, outlook-web-addins, sideloading

I have created a web addin for Outlook. I have debugged the addin by sideloading from my localhost. I am now moving the addin to a remote server and I seem not to be able to get the addin installed. I changed the urls in the manifest to a hosted url. I have gotten a variety of errors. But the most frequent is an error during install (Installation failed - Internal server error occurred). Is there any any procedure to follow for migrating the addin to a web url? I thought this would be a simple transistion. :-)

The url for my manifest has the format of https://example.com/myaddins/companyname/manifest.xml

[image]

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of any error to diagnose and give you the solution. I am not getting any errors after moving to cloud

Comment: Tom - Most probably the URL is not a problem. This should be quite straightforward I wonder if by any chance we can get a copy of your manifest?

Comment: Tom - Hit send too soon . This should be quite straightforward, basically replacing the domain of all the URLs within the manifest should suffice.  I wonder if by any chance we can get a copy of your manifest? did you used yo-office to create your project.. if you can share more detail we will be able to help you more effectively. Thanks !

Comment: also... I am assuming you are testing on the same machine, please make sure to either uninstall your manifest with localhost (or change the manifest ID) you cannot have duplicate IDs.